# Laravel and client side datatable

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

At work we have better computer than the server so I want to use client-side datatable to display large set of data.

But I don't find a lot of tutorials about client side datatable and laravel.

I use yajra package and here my simple code for server side datatable with laravel 5.4.

Route.php :

```
Route::get('/users/serverSide', [
    'as'   => 'users.serverSide',
    'uses' => function () {
        $users = App\User::select(['id', 'name', 'email', 'created_at']);
        return Datatables::of($users)->make();
    }
]);

Route::get('/table', function () {
    return view('users.table');
});
```

Table.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<table class="datatable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Created at</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ route('users.serverSide') }}'
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

I know serverSide must set to false and I must return all data as json. It's this part I don't achieve as I'm new to laravel.

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch all users on the Laravel side (`Route.php`), as shown on the [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) documentation:

```
return datatables()
    ->eloquent(User::select(['id', 'name', 'email', 'created_at'])->get())
    ->toJson();
```

*I'm assuming you're using the latest yajra/laravel-datatables*